# Express Passport.js Success redirect doesn't load page, request keeps pending

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js, passport-local

I am trying to do a basic username/password authentication using passport.js and passport local.

While `failureRedirect` does exactly what it is supposed to do, (redirects to a specified page), `successRedirect` keeps pending with the request for its specified page, and after some time, it returns `empty response`.

http://www.deviantpics.com/VdG

As you can see in this picture, when it is requesting dashboard, it says that its size is `0B`, but when I go on that dashboard without redirecting it says it has `1.6B`.

I have looked all over Stackoverflow, and I couldn't find an answer that would help me.

Could you please check my code and suggest something before I go berserk?

This is passport load code

```
//set expression
var expressSession = require('express-session');
app.use(expressSession({
    secret: credentials.session.secret
}));

//set passport
var passport = require('passport');

var localStrategy = require('./strategies/auth/local.js');
passport.use('local', localStrategy);

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
        done(err, user);
    });
});

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

routes.js

```
module.exports = function(app) {

//main
app.get('/', main.home);
app.get('/login', main.login);
app.get('/signup', main.signup);
app.post('/login', auth.loginLocal);
app.post('/signup', main.checkSignup);

//user
app.get('/user/dashboard', user.dashboard);
app.get('/user/addmemory', user.addMemory);
app.get('/user/memory', user.memory);
```

login function

```
exports.loginLocal = passport.authenticate('local', {
    successRedirect: '/user/dashboard',
    failureRedirect: '/login'
});
```

local strategy

```
var localAuthStrategy = new LocalStrategy(function(username, password, done) {

    User.findOne({
        username: username
    }, function(err, user) {
        if (err) {
            return done(err);
        }

        if (!user) {
            return done(null, false, {
                message: 'Incorrect username'
            });
        }

        if (!user.validPassword(password)) {
            return done(null, false, {
                message: 'Incorrect password'
            });
        }

        return done(null, user);
    });


});
```

dashboard function

```
exports.dashboard = function(req, res) {
    res.render('user/dashboard', {
        layout: 'user'
    });
};
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found an answer to my question, the problem was that the User model was not defined in the script where serializeUser and deserializeUser were defined.
I could not figure out what was going on, because I did not define any action in catch all handler, so a thing to remember, make sure to have catch all handler defined to know what is happening

```
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: Similarly for me I had forgotten to put the parenthesis at the end of serializeUser() - silently didn't redirect, but no errors. Even worse was the application worked just fine when entering wrong user details.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem as your a few days back and what I found was that I forgot to put parenthesis at the end of the `serializeUser` and `deserializeUser` functions.
I was actually using the `passport-local-mongoose` package for the respective functions. But it must be noted that in `app.use()` the functions are called and executed for all the template files so, we do use parenthesis with the names of the functions.